# Jmeter reporting higher load time

Tags: time, jmeter, load, report, performance-testing

I am performing baseline performance test on a project. Average load time reported by jmeter is much higher than actual load time in browser(fresh- no cache and cookies).
What will be the issue?

Comment: How long are the jmeter and actual load times? How often did you measure?

Comment: I've checked with a firefox add-on, it shows load time approx 9 secs and jmeter giving 42 secs.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to check the following:

1. **Load generator overload.** Re-run JMeter test with one user/thread and compare with Firefox. If the results will be comparable then the response time in JMeter may be excessive due to its overload. Try to address it by adding more load generators.
2. **Inaccurate browser emulation.** If even with one user the response time in the load test is higher, then it can be caused by inaccurate emulation of browser paralel connections. To troubleshoot it, compare waterfall diagrams. To get it from Firefox, use Firebug. Route JMeter traffic through [Fiddler](http://executeautomation.com/blog/jmeter-with-fiddler-series/) which displays the waterfall on the Timeline tab. If the waterfalls are different, you may have the following issue: a web browser downloads resources in parallel, while by default JMeter replays recorded traffic sequentially. To fix it, add these settings: [Simulating browsers using JMeter](http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/simulating-browsers-using-jmeter).

Comment: for info, if user is using 3.0, simulation is much more close to browser than in previous versions. 6 parallel download occur reusing the connection as browser would do.

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking with browser during the load test ? or at another time ?
In the latter case, you would be comparing apples and oranges.

Are you using JMeter GUI mode ? if yes, it's a bad practice, GUI mode is for scripting, NON GUI mode for load testing:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

How much threads are you using ? and which version of Jmeter ?
For embedded resources testing, 3.0 is the most realistic and performing:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13485902)

Comment: @eisbehr, I am not sure you read my answer. If you read it carefully : First Question is in fact an answer telling user to ensure he tests under load. Second question is an answer highlighting a well-known issue related to load testing with GUI. Third question asks user to ensure he uses 3.0 version and only here is there a little request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever you run performance tests instead of Average response times, always consider 90th percentile. In some cases avg. response time is skewed even if one request takes long to respond. So please check 90th Percentile.
2. If you are running the test with multiple users, try to hit the application from browser while load test is going on and check the response time on browser. This will tell you if your observation is correct.
3. The load generator may not be able to establish enough connections due to which you might see higher response time. Check load generator utilization in case if you doubt. In some cases load generator itself can't generate enough load.
4. Check your sever utilization when you run the performance test. This will give you an idea if the application is not able to handle the load or if it's the issue with load generator.
5. If you are running tests from UI mode, please try to run tests with non-UI mode. (Can you specify with how many users you are running these tests?)
6. Increase JMeter memory if you see issue with load generator and keep eye on load generator CPU usage too.
7. Check if load generator and browser from which you are hitting the application are on the same network and check network latency to check if there is network problem.